# Python List Comprehension With Equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I need to turn this into a list comprehension.  I have been stuck for a while. Any Ideas?

```
result = []
for i in range(length + 1):
    m = number * i
    result.append(m)
del result[0]
return result
```

Comment: Why do you need it as a list comprehension? Can you include some of your failed attempts?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
[number*i for i in range(length+1)][1:]
```

This iterates over the `range(length+1)` multiplying each to the number and storing in a list. Then I just take all the elements except the 0th.

You can start iterating from 1 to avoid generate 0th element in the first place, as suggested by @wwii

```
[number*i for i in range(1,length+1)] #or simply range(length)
```

Comment: Why not just `[number*i for i in range(1,length+1)]`?

Comment: Makes sense. But OP is doing a separate delete. Wanted to preserve that as a separate option. Updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Or ```[number*(i+1) for i in range(length)]```

Comment: Maybe even `list(range(number,(number*length)+1,number))`.